# Variables in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, variables

I was wondering if there is a known technique for saving and using variables in an SqlLite database.

I am looking for something like the `$something` variables one can find under Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't find any builtin solution for this, so I solved it by having a global table with Key,Value pairs

Here is the C# class i made to wrap this nicely

```
public class SQLiteVariable
{
    public SQLiteVariable() : this (null, string.Empty)
    {}
    public SQLiteVariable(SQLiteConnection connection) : this(connection, string.Empty)
    {}
    public SQLiteVariable(string name) : this(null, name)
    {}
    public SQLiteVariable(SQLiteConnection connection, string name)
    {
        Connection = connection;
        Name = name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The table name used for storing the database variables
    /// </summary>
    private const string VariablesTable = "__GlobalDatabaseVariablesTable";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the SQLite database connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The connection.</value>
    public SQLiteConnection Connection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the SQLite variable name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the SQLite variable value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The value.</value>
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            CheckEnviornemnt();
            var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Connection)
                          {
                              CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM " + VariablesTable + " WHERE Key=@VarName"
                          };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@VarName", Name));
            var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return returnValue as string;
        }
        set
        {
            CheckEnviornemnt();
            // Assume the variable exists and do an update
            var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Connection)
            {
                CommandText = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + VariablesTable + " (Key, Value) VALUES(@VarName, @Value)"
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Value", value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@VarName", Name));
            var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    private void CheckEnviornemnt()
    {
        if (Connection == null) throw new ArgumentException("Connection was not initialized");
        var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Connection)
        {
            CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+VariablesTable+" (Key VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY, Value VARCHAR(256));"
        };
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```